# Plotting 6 Linear functions in one graph

Tags: pgfplots, plot

i am stuck about drawing 6 linear functions in one graph  which are

- f_1(x)=  18x-9
- f_2(x)= -17x+8
- f_3(x)= -12x+6
- f_4(x)=  4x-2
- f_5(x)= -3x+1
- f_6(x)=  (\Pi /2)x

f_i : [0,1]-> R where  i=1,2,..6 .Thanks in advance

So far I rearrange my code as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1.0]
    \begin{axis}[
width=10cm,
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$\varphi_{i}(x)$,
ymin=-10,axis on top=true,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle, 
grid=major,
legend pos=outer north east
                    ]
\addplot [blue, line width = 1, smooth, domain=0:1] {18*x-9};
\addplot [red, line width=1,smooth,domain=0:1] {-17*x +8};
\addplot [yellow, line width=1,smooth,domain=0:1] {-12*x+6};
\addplot [green, line width=1,smooth,domain=0:1] {4*x-2};
\addplot [pink, line width=1,smooth,domain=0:1] {-3*x+1};
\addplot [orange, line width=1,smooth,domain=0:1] {(3/2) *x};

\node [fill=black, circle, scale=0.3] at (axis cs: {10/21},{-3/7}) {};
\node [fill=black, circle, scale=0.3] at (axis cs: {1/2},{-1/2}) {};
\node [below left] at (axis cs: {1/2},{-1/2}) {$\frac{10}{21},\frac{-3}{7}$};
\node [below right] at (axis cs: {1/2},{-1/2}) {$(\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}$};

\legend  {$\varphi_1 (x)=18 x - 9$,
          $\varphi _2 (x)=-17x+8$,
          $\varphi_3 (x)=-12x+6$,
          $\varphi_4 (x)=4x-2$,
          $\varphi_5 (x)=-3x+1$,
          $\varphi_6 (x)=x{\displaystyle\pi/2}$
         };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but i have problems in put name on intersection point. they are not look good as much as i think :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Well, this site (mostly) not provide service "do-it-for-me". Show us, what you try so far and where you stuck in your efforts :). Then we can more easily help you. Also on the right side of your question you have listed to questions related to yours. See, if one of them is useful for you.

Comment: i got it sorry for the language that i used :) i spend like 1.5 hours for plotting with the way i know and i am getting and getting error which is " couldn't find the pst-arrow". it was a request :3

Comment: Please show your code. I anticipate, that this error is easy to repair (but not me, I'm not `pstricks` man :( )

Comment: `pst-arrow` was recently split from `pstricks-add`. You probably should update. Which distribution do you have?

Comment: That's `pgfplots` code, what does `pstricks` or `pst-arrow` have to do with this? Edit: I changed the tag accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As Zarko said, TeX Stack Exchange is usually not the do-it-for-me site, but since you're new, I'll make an exception. We're going to plot with `tikz` and `pgfplots` packages (and `amsmath`, in case you use any exotic symbols). Here is our code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10, axis lines=center, axis equal]

\addplot[domain=-10:10, color=blue,]{18*x-9};

\addplot[domain=-10:10, color=red,]{-17*x+8};

\addplot[domain=-10:10, color=yellow,]{-12*x+6};

\addplot[domain=-10:10, color=green,]{4*x-2};

\addplot[domain=-10:10, color=pink,]{-3*x+1};

\addplot[domain=-10:10, color=orange,]{pi/2*x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result.

[image]

UPDATE: Sorry for not including ***your*** code in my answer, you posted it after my repsonse was already finished.

Comment: Thank you for being interested in my request, i have also get information from your code. thank you :)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad my post helped you. Have a nice day, I wish you lots of success with LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a `pin` is a better way of highlighting those intersections. Or are you going to mark more of the intersections?

Note that I simplified the code a bit, moving domain specification and line width setting to the `axis` options, so that you don't to add it to all the plots.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$\varphi_{i}(x)$,
ymin=-10,axis on top=true,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle, 
grid=major,
legend pos=outer north east,
legend style={nodes={anchor=west}}, %% added
every axis plot/.append style={ %% these will apply to all plots
  line width=1pt,
  samples=2, % don't need more for straight lines
  domain=0:1
}
]

\addplot [blue] {18*x-9};
\addplot [red] {-17*x +8};
\addplot [yellow] {-12*x+6};
\addplot [green] {4*x-2};
\addplot [pink] {-3*x+1};
\addplot [orange] {(3/2) *x};

\node [fill=black, circle, scale=0.3, pin=below:{$\bigl(\frac{10}{21},\frac{-3}{7}\bigr)$}] at (axis cs: {10/21},{-3/7}) {};
\node [fill=black, circle, scale=0.3, pin=above:{$\bigl(\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}\bigr)$}] at (axis cs: {1/2},{-1/2}) {};



\legend  {$\varphi_1 (x)=18 x - 9$,
          $\varphi _2 (x)=-17x+8$,
          $\varphi_3 (x)=-12x+6$,
          $\varphi_4 (x)=4x-2$,
          $\varphi_5 (x)=-3x+1$,
          $\varphi_6 (x)=x{\displaystyle\pi/2}$
         };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I write  `xtick={0,1}` insted of arraging the points , thanks for the idea :)

Comment: @AlperErdem That also removes the grid though.

Comment: yes i aware of the consequences of that wrong move :D

Comment: @AlperErdem You could try `xtick={0,1},grid=both,minor x tick num=4` if you want a grid, but no ticklabels for 0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8.